# Temporal coincidences of negative votes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, users

Is it possible that a user after just a few minutes that I have been logged on Physics.SE contextually receives a negative vote?

Is it possible that a user who has a high number of reputation can have the privilege to spy also the users when are they just connected?? After a few minutes that I switched from TeX.SE. to Physics.SE I have received another downvote, almost immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't entirely follow what you're concerned about here with respect to downvotes, but everyone can see on your profile when you last took an action on the site (subject to caching, this time is only accurate to within a few minutes): [image]

Beyond that there is nothing other users could see of your activity - unless of course you do something visible like write a comment or post a question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But your screenshot it is done few minutes ago.