# Serial voting: procedure for to advise the managers of the SE site

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, voting

I would like to find out information about voting behaviour against me on this site (Main and/or Meta). Does such information exist? If so, where can I find it?

A stalker or more stalkers on Stack Exchange is downvoting every new post I make. How can I find out who it is?

What indication should be reported to the managers of Stack Exchange?

Is it possible to consider these links

1. https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/781493/25-most-downvoted-users
   and
2. https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.physics/query/691667/top-downvoters

to identify a possible downvoting stalker?

Comment: not sure what you’re gonna get from such a query: the downvotes are not attributed and it would be dangerous to draw conclusions from such a list.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It is not dangerous absolutely. Some users have been suspended for days, weeks and years. I don't jump to conclusions. But I do reflect and meditate before writing or giving negative votes. Look at my profiles and you'll get a better idea of how many negative votes I assign.

Comment: Related (your previous post here): *[Temporal coincidences of negative votes](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13445)*

Comment: What is your real question? *"A stalker on Stack Exchange is downvoting every new post I make. How can I find out who it is?"* Or something else? Can you [edit your question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/13718/edit) to make it clearer?

Comment: Related (cross site): *[How to identify a downvoting stalker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159888)*, *[Stalking, bullying and downvoting on Stack Overflow-related sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229559)*, and *[Someone joined SE in order to stalk me, but hasn't broken any site rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246089)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen After my question on the meta PSE site I got 3 unexplained negative votes on the main PSE site today that are almost consecutive. Please, can you see if now my question is more clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking for, but the same SEDE queries you have on TeX.SE can be used on Physics.SE.

Comment: I would like to know the history of all my downvotes as someone continually harasses me and I would like to know the details. Could you please explain how and what is the link? I have tried but entering my ID number of PSE does not give me any information about PSE. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano To run your linked queries against Physics rather than Tex Meta, change `/meta.tex/` to `/physics/` in the URL. The second query gives an error when called on Physics; I haven't tried to debug it.

Comment: For posterity, the bug is simply that there exists a user with 0 upvotes and >1 downvotes on Physics.SE (but not on Tex.SE), so there is a Division by Zero error while calculating the ratio.

Comment: Very kind moderators: thank you very much for your answer. The same for @rob. Thank your very much for you answer/comment.

Comment: @NiharKarve The reference on TeX.SE was just so I could understand what is the link where I can do some analysis or evaluations. Greetings.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Can you [add](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/13718/edit) some of the information in comments here to your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to know the history of all my downvotes as someone continually harasses me and I would like to know the details

If you want to see a list of all the times you have downvoted other people's posts, it is available on your profile, under Activity > Votes.

On the other hand, if you want information on who has downvoted your posts, it is simply and unambiguously *not* available. This is an explicit choice on the part of SE and the developers have spent significant effort to prevent any loopholes.

If someone is downvoting your posts inappropriately and at a large scale, there are several safeguard mechanisms built into the system that will detect it and delete the votes. If you feel that you personally (as opposed to your posts and their content) are being downvoted inappropriately targeted, raise a custom flag on one of the affected posts so moderators can take a look (and, if needed, escalate to SE staff).

Comment: In fact, I want to report this to the SE staff so that we have everything we need. Thank you very much for your answer and I send you my greetings. However as soon as I ask a question automatically negative votes appear.

Comment: @Sebastiano There is no evidence that any user is following your posts and downvoting them on a large scale. Have you considered the possibility that there is something wrong with your posts that attracts downvotes from people who see your question on the front page?

Comment: @Chris I have considered also this. But yesterday I have received three consecutive serial downvotes on the main site PSE.

Comment: @Sebastiano Getting multiple down votes doesn't mean it's serial.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Hence when I see consecutives downvotes (with an small interval of time) it is ok. I have understood.

Comment: @BioPhysicist it remains quite an extraordinary coincidence that Sebastiano should get 3 downvotes apparently clustered in time (I cannot verify his claim) after minimal activity in over the last month.  It *can* happen but what are the odds of the downvotes being on 3 distinct answers or questions?  If such a pattern is repeated the odds are even smaller.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sorry, I didn't realize they were three different posts.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Sorry I wrote poorly: I’m not sure they are (I can’t verify) but I *think* (from context) they are.